# Linking against an old version of libc to provide greater application coverage

Tags: linux, linker, libc

Linux binaries are usually dynamically linked to the core system library (libc). This keeps the memory footprint of the binary quite small but binaries which are dependent on the latest libraries will not run on older systems. Conversely, binaries linked to older libraries will run happily on the latest systems.

Therefore, in order to ensure our application has good coverage during distribution we need to figure out the oldest libc we can support and link our binary against that.

How should we determine the oldest version of libc we can link to?

Comment: Not mentioned in any of the answers: https://github.com/wheybags/glibc_version_header ... probably could take some updating.

Comment: Another one that may come in handy: https://www.lordaro.co.uk/posts/2018-08-26-compiling-glibc.html

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Work out which symbols in your executable are creating the dependency on the undesired version of glibc.

```
$ objdump -p myprog
...
Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691972 0x00 05 GLIBC_2.3
    0x09691a75 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.2.5

$ objdump -T myprog | fgrep GLIBC_2.3
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3   realpath
```

Look within the depended-upon library to see if there are any symbols in older versions that you can link against:

```
$ objdump -T /lib/libc.so.6 | grep -w realpath
0000000000105d90 g    DF .text  0000000000000021 (GLIBC_2.2.5) realpath
000000000003e7b0 g    DF .text  00000000000004bf  GLIBC_2.3   realpath
```

We're in luck!

Request the version from `GLIBC_2.2.5` in your code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__asm__(".symver realpath,realpath@GLIBC_2.2.5");

int main () {
    realpath ("foo", "bar");
}
```

Observe that GLIBC_2.3 is no longer needed:

```
$ objdump -p myprog
...
Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5

$ objdump -T myprog | grep realpath
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 realpath
```

For further information, see http://web.archive.org/web/20160107032111/http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=103.

Comment: I would also add that often there's only one or two symbols causing a dependency on a new glibc version, so if like me you are worried you're going to have to list hundreds of symbols to remove a dependency, you won't.

Comment: dietlibc is also worth looking at.

Comment: Or if you can link statically (i.e. your code is not a plugin and won't use plugins), you can also look at musl-libc. I have found oftentimes that the statically linked programs with musl-libc are smaller than their dynamically linked glibc counterparts.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy about five years later, this comment came around to help me out in a major way.  :)

Comment: This just forces linking to an older symbol version, without any regard for the reasons that the newer version was created. Doing this in general could have all kinds of problems. If using old symbol versions is needed, compilation against headers of that old version is needed as well. This approach might work with some really simple calls that don't have pointers to system defined structs, but still is not advisable.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I wanted to compile gnumake on ubuntu-latest, but target old linuxes, so `__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5")` avoided linking to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14, but I had to add this directive to `makeint.h` (ie, to every compilation unit, not just to one. Any idea why adding it to main.c alone didn't work? (both 2.2.5 and 2.14 symbols were linked in that case)

Comment: Translations units are complied independently from one another. The `.symver` directive can only affect the current translation unit. Therefore putting it in a `.h` file is the way to get the directive included in all translation units. These days it's _way_ easier to build inside a container created from an image of the oldest distribution you want to support, rather than much around with `symver`...

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, @Sam's solution doesn't work well in my situation. But according to his way, I found my own way to solve that.

This is my situation:

I'm writing a C++ program using the Thrift framework(it's an RPC middleware). I prefer static link to dynamic link, so my program is linked to *libthrift.a* statically instead of *libthrift.so*. However, *libthrift.a* is dynamically linked to glibc, and since my *libthrift.a* is build on my system with glibc 2.15, my *libthrift.a* uses **memcpy** of version 2.14(**memcpy@GLIBC_2.14**) provided by glibc 2.15.

But the problem is that our server machines have only the glibc version 2.5 which has only **memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5**. It is much lower than **memcpy@GLIBC_2.14**. So, of course, my server program can't run on those machines.

And I found this solusion:

1. Using .symver to obtain the ref to **memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5**.
2. Write my own **__wrap_memcpy** function which just calls **memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5** directly.
3. When linking my program, add *-Wl,--wrap=memcpy* option to gcc/g++.

The code involved in steps 1 and 2 is here: https://gist.github.com/nicky-zs/7541169

Comment: The problem appears to be with `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, which defaults to 1 on newer GCC versions at certain optimization levels. With that enabled, some of the functions are masked. For me undefining and subsequently redefining it to 0 makes the above solution work (GCC 4.8.4).

Comment: 9 years later, it saved me a lot of time. Many thanks!

Answer (score 12):

To do this in a more automated fashion, you can use the following script to create a list of all the symbols that are newer in your GLIBC than in a given version (set on line 2). It creates a `glibc.h` file (filename set by the script argument) which contains all the necessary `.symver` declarations. You can then add `-include glibc.h` to your CFLAGS to make sure it gets picked up everywhere in your compilation.

This is sufficient if you don't use any static libraries that were compiled without the above include. If you do, and you don't want to recompile, you can use `objcopy` to create a copy of the library with the symbols renamed to the old versions. The second to bottom line of the script creates a version of your system `libstdc++.a` that will link against the old glibc symbols. Adding `-L.` (or `-Lpath/to/libstdc++.a/`) will make your program statically link libstdc++ without linking in a bunch of new symbols. If you don't need this, delete the last two lines and the `printf ... redeff` line.

```
#!/bin/bash
maxver=2.9
headerf=${1:-glibc.h}
set -e
for lib in libc.so.6 libm.so.6 libpthread.so.0 libdl.so.2 libresolv.so.2 librt.so.1; do
objdump -T /usr/lib/$lib
done | awk -v maxver=${maxver} -vheaderf=${headerf} -vredeff=${headerf}.redef -f <(cat <<'EOF'
BEGIN {
split(maxver, ver, /\./)
limit_ver = ver[1] * 10000 + ver[2]*100 + ver[3]
}
/GLIBC_/ {
gsub(/\(|\)/, "",$(NF-1))
split($(NF-1), ver, /GLIBC_|\./)
vers = ver[2] * 10000 + ver[3]*100 + ver[4]
if (vers > 0) {
    if (symvertext[$(NF)] != $(NF-1))
        count[$(NF)]++
    if (vers <= limit_ver && vers > symvers[$(NF)]) {
        symvers[$(NF)] = vers
        symvertext[$(NF)] = $(NF-1)
    }
}
}
END {
for (s in symvers) {
    if (count[s] > 1) {
        printf("__asm__(\".symver %s,%s@%s\");\n", s, s, symvertext[s]) > headerf
        printf("%s %s@%s\n", s, s, symvertext[s]) > redeff
    }
}
}
EOF
)
sort ${headerf} -o ${headerf}
objcopy --redefine-syms=${headerf}.redef /usr/lib/libstdc++.a libstdc++.a
rm ${headerf}.redef
```

Comment: Why the `sort`?

Comment: It's not really necessary, it just makes the file more reproducible if you want to check it in to source control or prevent your build system rebuilding everything

Comment: This `objcopy --redefine-syms` solution doesn't actually work, and it took me hours to find why. objcopy tries to do a string match-replace for the given symbols, but the versions of the symbols are _not_ expressed as strings . objcopy simply doesn't work on them -- the versions are expressed in a lookup table, which objcopy 2.20.50 does not attempt to modify. Ever. There _is_ a "default" symbol which can be changed this way -- `symbol@@1.2.3` can be changed.

Comment: I thought I had that working, but I mustn't have tested it properly if that's the case, sorry. I didn't end up using that part, I settled on recompiling my deps since it seems less likely to introduce runtime problems.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much! Helps when your build machine is newer than target. In my case, I'm building on newest Ubuntu focal (glibc 2.31-0ubuntu9.1)  for Debian buster (2.28-10). If maxver is too low, it will produce a relocation error like "symbol clock_gettime version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference" but with right maxver (2.20) it produces a working binary. This should really be part of glibc manual!

Comment: It's also worth checking out crosstool-ng to build a toolchain with old glibc and new GCC/libstdc++

Comment: @patstew this was a case of "build on your laptop - run on an embedded device". I didn't want to set up a separate build VM, chroot or anything like it. Software is a fork of ffmpeg to stream directly from H264-enabled camera https://github.com/articice/FFmpeg/tree/uvcvideo-patch-rebase

Comment: @ArticIceJuice that is exactly the error I'm getting, do you know why this happens? If I use a higher maxver value that works in a current version of glibc, could it return this error in future versions? Thanks!

Comment: I think they moved clock_gettime from librt to libc around 2.17 or something, make sure you have -lrt in your linker args. If that's not it maybe that move is causing other problems due to the header files or something?

Answer (score 6):

glibc 2.2 is a pretty common minimum version. However finding a build platform for that version may be non-trivial.

Probably a better direction is to think about the oldest OS you want to support and build on that.

Comment: Makes sense, I just hoping for some juicy low hanging fruit that I might pluck from the branches of opportunity :-)

Comment: Eh? http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/ says glibc *2.17*, released 2012-12-25, is the latest version. How can 2.2 be a common minimum?

Comment: @DouglasLeeder: Oh, right; I was mistaken for a while. :D Thanks!