# Ubuntu-compiled program to run on Unix webserver

Tags: apache, gcc, ubuntu, glibc, ada

I have compiled an Ada program on Ubuntu using GNAT.

Afterwards, I tried a few test runs with that program and it worked properly.

But when I uploaded this to my Apache (UNIX) webserver and tried to run the program, there was no output. Why is this so?

Could it be that programs which have been compiled on Ubuntu don't work on a UNIX server?

(Sorry for the stupid question!)

**Linux version of the system I use for compiling (uname -a):**

```
Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu x86-64 GNU/Linux
```

**Linux version of the system I want to run the program on later (uname -a):**

```
Linux 2.6.37-he-xeon-64gb+1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**For compiling on the Ubuntu machine, I use:**

```
gnatmake -O3 myprogram -bargs -static
```

Comment: What specific operating system is your webserver? (what is the output of 'uname -a', for starters)

Comment: it wouldn't surprise me that switching operating systems would necessitate a recompile, but I'm not familiar with Ada/GNAT

Comment: Thank you, blueshift and dldnh! The server is: "Linux 2.6.37-he-xeon-64gb+1 i686 GNU/Linux"

Comment: Try running the (an) Ada program in a terminal shell on the web server? (My guess would be, some problem with shared libraries, in which case `ldd` should give a clue).

Comment: Yes I try to run this program with the help of PHP's function shell_exec(). The problem is: I got a pre-compiled version that works - even when I use PHP to access it. But the one I compiled does not.

Comment: What happens when you run it from the command line?  Is there an error message?

Comment: I don't have the possibility to run it from the command line, unfortunately. So the only way to use it, for me, is those PHP functions.

Comment: You want to crosscompile from 64-bit to 32-bit. Not that easy.

Comment: Thank you very much oenone! So I have to install Ubuntu as a 32-bit version and then it will probably work, right?

Comment: I have now updated my Ubuntu for compiling to the 32-bit version. When I then run my Ubuntu-compiled version on the webserver and try `ldd myprogram`, it returns `statically linked` now instead of `not a dynamic executable`. Is this good news? (I can't see any output, though, so it doesn't really work yet.)

Comment: "cross compile" is a bit over the top for this scenario. It's trivial to produce 32bit binaries on a 64bit system. Use gcc -m32

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you build a GNAT program (`gnatmake my_program`), by default it links against dynamic libraries (`libgnat.so`, `libgnarl.so`). These libraries are part of the GNAT system and are very unlikely to be available on your web server.

If you say `ldd my_program` it will show you the shared libraries used.

You can force the build to use the static GNAT libraries by saying

```
gnatmake my_program -bargs -static
```

(the `-bargs -static` must come after regular flags like `-O2`).

Edit: [more info on `-bargs` and friends](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Mode-Switches-for-gnatmake.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! And when I use `gnatmake -O3 -bargs -static myprogram` for example, it will (probably) work on my webserver?

Comment: Did `ldd my_program` (on the original) show shared libs? If it did, then yes, you stand a better chance. `-bargs -static` needs to come last, as I showed; the way you have it, the `myprogram` would be sent only to the binder, not to the builder.

Comment: When I run `ldd myprogram` on my webserver, it says `not a dynamic executable` whereas for the pre-compiled (working) program I get `linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000) libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb777e000) libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7640000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7793000) `

Comment: Now, after recompiling the program with `-bargs -static`, the size of the program increased from about 800kB to 1100kB. But nevertheless, `ldd` says: "not a dynamic executable".

Comment: webserver is 32-bit, it won't execute 64-bit executables.

Comment: When using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu for compiling, `ldd myprogram` does answer with `statically linked` now instead of `not a dynamic executable`. But there's still no output.

Comment: Is it executable? what's the return value in the shell you started it? are you sure the program produces output?

Comment: I don't know if it is executable. How do I check this? I'm sure that it produces output because when I run this program under Unix, it does. But PHP's `shell_exec()` has no output for this program. But if I take the pre-compiled version (that someone else has compiled, but I modified it) it has output - both under Ubuntu and with PHP's `shell_exec()`.

Comment: The problem is that `ldd` returns `statically linked` for my own compilation but the list of libraries for the version that someone else has compiled.

Comment: For my own compilation, `ldd` says `linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000) libgnat-4.4.so.1 => not found libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb780e000) libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb76cf000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7823000)`. Could this be the problem? When you compare it to the output named in the comment above, the only difference is that libgcc is "not found".

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the server has the libraries your app links against or link them statically like already suggested by others. Some other comments point out that you need to "cross compile" or that the server won't run 64 bit binaries. This is easily solved unless the app you're building is very complex.

gnatmake --GCC='gcc -m32'

Will make a binary that will run on a 32bit system. However the chief problem is that the servers (g)libc is very likely to be older than what's on your ubunu box. Programs compiled against newer glibc will not necessarily run on systems with an older glibc installed.

for more info and plenty more links, look here:

[Linking against an old version of libc to provide greater application coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032373/linking-against-an-old-version-of-libc-to-provide-greater-application-coverage)
[How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version)

edit:
Besides, apache may not be configured to accept invocation of external binaries. Have you "tried to run the program" with something you know exists on the server? Try to run something trivial like /bin/ls to make sure your method of running the program works. Look at the logs if it doesn't work. Programs need to be executable, by the way: chmod 755 /path/to/webeserver/uploads/ada-app

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem of cross-compiling is already solved as I'm using a 32-bit Ubuntu now. The question that is still open is why `ldd` returns `statically linked` for my own compilation but a list of libraries for the pre-compiled version. Is the pre-compiled version not statical so that it doesn't include the libraries and has dependences?

Comment: And as I have statically linked the libraries, Apache doesn't need to allow the invocation of external libraries, does it?

Comment: When I do NOT statically link the program (as the pre-compiled version is), `ldd` says `linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000) libgnat-4.4.so.1 => not found libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb780e000) libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb76cf000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7823000)`. Is this the problem? It says "not found" ...

Comment: Marco, the GNAT shared libraries being not found is why I recommended `-static` in the first place; the GNAT libraries are then linked in, so it doesn’t matter whether the webserver has them installed or not (it probably doesn’t). Have you tried building a simple ‘hello world’ application and just running that on the webserver?

Comment: Yes, I know, but the static program didn't produce any output so I tried a dynamic one again. The hello_world program does produce output. It works.

Comment: Even `./programname 2>&1` doesn't show any output. I'm really becoming desperate.

Comment: And `/bin/ls` works, by the way. It shows the full list of files in the directory. And maybe even directories, but there are none.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just compile it on your Webserver instead of your local machine ?

Aswell `cat /etc/issue` or `cat /etc/release` could give us some information about the distribution you're using.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine, this command with "release" does say that there is no such directory. The command with "issue" says it's `Ubuntu 11.10 \n \l`. On my webserver, both commands produce no output. Is this the problem? No output here as well ...

Comment: @MarcoW. Are you sure you're running Linux on your web server?

Comment: Yes, of course. See the note in the question: `Linux 2.6.37-he-xeon-64gb+1 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: does apt-get update produce some output ? Then you should be able to download all the nessecary tools to your Webserver to compile your programm