# Unable to use std::chrono with std::future - GLIBCXX_3.4.19 not found

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cross-compiling, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to use `std::future::wait_for(std::chrono::duration)` in my application (in fact, I don't want to wait at all which makes this more frustrating, as you'll see), but in using anything from `std::chrono`, I am unable to run the application after cross-compiling it for my BeagleBone Black:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found
```

Until I add the following lines to my code, this project compiles and runs great with an older version of GLIBCXX, but just to be able to check if a future's value is ready without blocking, I suddenly need all these newer libraries:

```
if (myFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready)
    return true;
```

The BeagleBone Black comes with `GLIBCXX_3.4.17` from GCC 4.6.3 - I've checked the C++ headers on the system, and as I suspected, all the functionality I need from the chrono library is there. So why does it ask for version 3.4.19?

I tried updating and upgrading Debian with `sudo apt-get upgrade` in the hopes that the newer libraries would be added. This had no effect. Besides, I would *really* like to be able to run on the stock image.

So I tried statically linking `libstdc++` with `-static-libstdc++` added to my LD flags. Now I'm apparently missing `GLIBC-2.7` which can't be fixed in the same way with `-static-libgcc`

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe try with compiler flag `-D _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to select the pre `GCC 5` ABI? (GCC 5 introduced a new Binary Interface that is "switchable").

Comment: I tried the compiler flag as you suggested, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to compile with a previous version of the function that required 3.4.19 by following steps in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032373/linking-against-an-old-version-of-libc-to-provide-greater-application-coverage).

Firstly, I checked what was needed from 3.4.19:

```
$ objdump -T myapp | grep "GLIBCXX_3.4.19"
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.19 _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv
```

Then I searched for the same symbol in the library I have

```
$ objdump -T /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep "_ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv"
```

But this returned nothing. On a hunch, I tried finding just 'chrono' instead

```
$ objdump -T /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep "chrono"
00080828 g    DF .text  0000002a  GLIBCXX_3.4.11 _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv
0008ae38 g    DO .rodata    00000001  GLIBCXX_3.4.11 _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock12is_monotonicE
```

Bingo. While it's not an exact match, it looked good enough for me. I added an assembly directive to my source file to update the linkage for the  requested symbol.

```
__asm__(".symver _ZNSt6chrono3_V212system_clock3nowEv,_ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv@GLIBCXX_3.4.11");
```

While it now compiles and runs, I am unable to say for sure that this substitution works as I have other hurdles to get around however I think I'd be safe in saying it's a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It works the ".symver" change, but it will break your std::chrono timers and dates if you compile it with >= GCC 4.8, because std::chrono ABI had changes.
It will run with systems like Ubuntu 12.04 (GCC 4.6.3) but date & time will not be showed correctly.