# Linking static library compiled with g++ 7.2 using gcc 3.2.3

Tags: c++, gcc

I have an embedded application that has been written for gcc 3.2.3<sup>1</sup>, and I want to link a library, written by myself, and compiled using g++ 7.2.0.

I have already built and link a test library with almost no code, but now that I am trying something more relevant, I face some issues regarding undefined symbols. Currently, I have the following kind of errors:

> undefined reference to `__assert_func`

I do not get this error if I compile using g++ 3.2.3.

I want to use g++ 7.2.0 to have access to the new C++14 (maybe C++17) features and some new parts of the standard library (`std::chrono::duration`, etc.).

Is there a way to make this work?

I can fix the above issue by defining my own `__assert_func`:

```
extern "C" void __assert(const char *, int, const char *);

extern "C" void __assert_func(
    const char *file, int line, const char *, const char *e) {
    __assert(file, line, e);
}
```

...but I was wondering if there is a simpler way? In particular, there may be other name changes and I do not want to have to modify these everytime...

I assume I will not use new features that would require code that is not in the old gcc version (e.g., `std::thread` or `std::chrono::system_clock`).

---

Related:

- [Linking against an old version of libc to provide greater application coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032373/linking-against-an-old-version-of-libc-to-provide-greater-application-coverage), with "solutions" for dynamic libraries, but no better solutions than mine for static libraries (i.e., rewriting the missing symbols).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The application and the library are built using the `sparc-rtems` gcc toolchains, and some third party tools such as JamaicaVM. I cannot simply change the toolchain used to build the main application because there are many incompatibilities with the new compiler toolchain...</sub>

Comment: @VTT It's my code that contains such symbol. I have some `assert` in my code (currently for debugging purpose), and in the recent gcc versions, the `assert` macro calls `__assert_func`, while in old version it simply calls `__assert` and there are no `__assert_func` does not exist in the old libc.

Comment: Actually after rereading your question I've realized that you want to squeeze  static libraries build with newer toolchain into old toolchain. I doubt that this is going to work. You may check [gcc ABI policies](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). But even if no linker errors occurs it would probably not going to work correctly.

Comment: @VTT The current (dirty) fix actually works, it just boils down to finding the right symbols... I was just hoping there would an somehow simple way to tell gcc to build for old libraries, or maybe a list of changes between the two (even if these are years appart... ).

Comment: @VTT I would be interested to know what kind of problems could occur at runtime once the linker step succeed. That may change my approach on the actual problem.

Comment: Use older gcc to compile that code (along with library files supplied with older gcc version). There is a clear line in the link @VTT posted: `GCC 3.4.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.0 (Incompatible with previous)`. The only releable way would be to check gcc commits for changes. Or you can try linking both old and newer library with some objcopy renaming tricks.

Comment: @KamilCuk I would not have asked this question if I wanted to compile with the old version. The old gcc version is 3.1.3 which does not even have `c++0x`... The line you mentioned is the link is about `libstdc++`. I know there might be incompatibility issues in the C++ ABI, like different mangling or different class layout, but the interface between the two code is C, not C++, and as mentioned, I can manage to not rely on any external C++ dependencies (e.g., `std::chrono` templates classes do not require any external dependencies). [...]

Comment: @KamilCuk [...] I've kept going with my current approach and by being careful with what I am using, I did not face any issue except `__assert_func`. As I commented to @VTT, I am simply wondering what kind of runtime problems I could run in under the assumptions I mention in my answer (interface between code is C, no external libstdc++ dependencies, etc.).